# Page reload using angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-routing

I am newbie to `angularJS`. I have started learning with CRUD operation. I am getting a problem that when I `delete` an entry then the page should `reload`

I have gone through `$location` and `$route` too. and implementing as follow :

`config`

```
app.config( function ( $locationProvider, $routeProvider ) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/this',{
        templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }); 
});
```

and when action success then I am writing as :

```
$location.path('/this');
```

but when I do this then the `url` changes from `http://localhost/someapp` to `http://this` but the page does not refresh. What should I do in this case please help me guys ?

`Edit` :

Here is my `deletion code` :

```
$scope.deletecode = function (id) {
    name = '';
    if (confirm("are you sure to Delete the name")) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'rohit.php',
            data: {
                "name": name,
                "id": id,
                "delete": "true"
            },
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("data deleted successfully");
            $location.path('/this');
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Unable to load data.");
        });
    } else {
        alert("Data deletion cancelled by user ... ");
    }
};
```

On init I am getting the data from a php file :

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'test.php'
}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.samples = data;
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Unable to load data.");
});
```

all the data is stored in `$scope.samples` which returns two things `user_id` and `name`

Comment: I'm not sure you actually want to refresh the page. Deleting an item, if done correctly, will update the view without the need to refresh the page.

Comment: the view is not updated, how can I update the view, I am posting my deletion function

Comment: can't you use `location.reload();`? simple javascript method

Comment: If you absolutely must reload, just use `location.reload()` like @Satpal suggests. Your Angular will be completely reinitialized anyways once you refresh the page.

Comment: thanks Satpal and xbonez, +1 upvote

Comment: but whats about splice ??

Comment: `splice` is to delete the item from the array. The whole point of using Angular is to build single-page web-apps that don't need page loads or reloads. If you're going to reload the page everytime you delete or add an item, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: but in the above exaple I am not able to delete from array using splice, can you help me please ?

Comment: I hace updated my code, how can I use splice in my code ?

Comment: Why are you unable to delete? Find the right index, and you can delete. http://jsfiddle.net/YqQZ9/

Comment: Like I said in the comment in my answer, you need to loop over `$scope.samples` and find the index of the element you are deleting.

Comment: Here's a code sample for how you can find the index of an element: http://jsfiddle.net/YqQZ9/1/. I really recommend you spend some more time getting familiar with Javascript before jumping into Angular. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a great starting point.

Comment: Thanks I am able to find the index using : $scope.samples.splice( $scope.samples.indexOf(id), 1 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your http request is deleting the item from your server, but you are not deleting it from your client-side code, which is why your view is not updating. You want to remove it from you client-side code as well once it has been removed from the server:

```
// all items in an array
$scope.items = [item1, item2];
// delete an item
$scope.deletecode = function (id) {
    name = '';
    if (confirm("are you sure to Delete the name")) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'rohit.php',
            data: {
                "name": name,
                "id": id,
                "delete": "true"
            },
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("data deleted successfully");
            // at this point, the item has been deleted from your server
            // remove it from $scope.items as well
            // removes 1 item at index idx
            $scope.items.splice(idx, 1);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Unable to load data.");
        });
    } else {
        alert("Data deletion cancelled by user ... ");
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey what is idx, is it id in my case ?

Comment: idx is the index of the item in the array that you are deleting. You will need to track that. So, if you're deleting the first item, `idx = 0`. If you're deleting the last element, `idx = $scope.items.length - 1`

Comment: I am getting the data into view from a php file and storing into `$scope.samples = data`.it is giving user_id and name and after deletion  i am doing `$scope.samples.splice(user_id, 1)`. whats wrong with this ?

Comment: `user_id` is not the index. For example, if the first element in the array is a user with `user_id=1337`, the index is still 0. If you don't have the index, loop over the array and search for the index.

Comment: I had to add `$scope.$apply();` after the splice to make it work.